# About geting transaction id from paypal in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, paypal

I have implement paypal library for payment in my iphone project.

How can I retrieve transaction id after following method called successfully.

```
-(void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus {
    status = PAYMENTSTATUS_SUCCESS;
}

- (void)paymentLibraryExit 
{
    UIAlertView *alert1 = nil;

    switch (status) 
        {           
        case PAYMENTSTATUS_SUCCESS:            
                {
                   .......
                   ...........
                }
                ...............
                ..............
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got transaction id using paykey by api with following api detail:-
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/paymentdetails-api-operation

You can get transaction id by parsing data of response of following api request code:-

```
- (void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus {
    status = PAYMENTSTATUS_SUCCESS;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    NSString *parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"payKey=%@&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=%@",payKey,@"en_US"];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameterString length]];

    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //do post request for parameter passing 
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //passing key as a http header request 
    [theRequest addValue:api_username forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID"];

    //passing key as a http header request
    [theRequest addValue:api_password forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD"];

    [theRequest addValue:api_signature forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE"];

    [theRequest addValue:@"NV" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT"];

    [theRequest addValue:@"NV" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT"];

    [theRequest addValue:app_id forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( connection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you found the api_username, api_password and api_signature???? can´t find them :/

Comment: If you want api_username, api_password and api_signature for testing purpose then you can get it from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

Comment: If you want api_username, api_password and api_signature for original account then you can follow steps given from following link:- http://www.putler.com/support/faq/how-to-get-paypal-api-username-password-and-signature-information/ or https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/cps/merchant/wppro/WPProIntegrationSteps-outside

Comment: thanks... well now with the sandbox credentials it works like a charm, but when I use the live credentials it always throw the error that user isn't allowed to perform that action... the payments are getting delivered correctly... but when I try to get the transactionid it always throw that error... some ideas????

Comment: @Calleth'Zion'- I have used above method using old MPL library(see:- https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL). But I have not checked it using latest paypal library.

Answer (score 1):

The "payKey" in below method is the transactionID.

```
-(void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus {
    status = PAYMENTSTATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```