# How to get TransactionID on PayPal iOS SDK 1.0.1

Tags: ios6, paypal

How can i take TransactionId from iOS device using PayPal iOS SDK 1.0.1?!

Thank you

Comment: Seriously, doesn't anybody have access to google anymore? Possible duplicate of [About geting transaction id from paypal in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482965/about-geting-transaction-id-from-paypal-in-iphone)

Comment: Yes but i see now there's no PayPalPaymentStatus,or maybe im not knowing how to access(import) it?! That's why im asking for SDK 1.0.1

Comment: I dont think answer is there. im trying to use it but it shows me error in XCode because of PayPalPaymentStatus

Comment: So one thing that is severely missing from this question is: What have you tried? What were you expecting to happen? What actually happened? Did you get an error? Explain to us what you've done to try to help yourself, and we will build on that.

Comment: I implemented PayPal example if you saw it and if you are informed with latest update of PayPal for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a fair question. The new PayPal iOS SDK 1.0.1 doesn't provide TransactionID anymore. What you get from the SDK is something called "Proof of Purchase". You can find the details on this page here : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Is there a reason why you need the TrasactionID specifically ?

Comment: Actually i need to save it in database.We are doing so when we do payments through paypal from web,we save TransactionID to our datbase.?!Any guidance how can i get it!?.Thank you for your answer

Comment: ah - this is going to be little messy when you combine classic APIs and new APIs (which is what the new iOS SDK is based on). In the new APIs (iOS SDK), the underlying Sale transaction below the Payment is a "transaction" and it's ID is nothing but the TransactionID you would get from other APIs too. So when you get the proof of purchase from iOS SDK, from your server side, make a GET on /v1/payments/payment/{paument-id-from-iOS-SDK} to obtain the details. In the details you will notice related-resources as "Sale". The ID of that Sale is the "TransactionId" that you would need.

Comment: here are the details: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource

Comment: Thanks Praveen,one more thing i'd like to ask because im hardly finding anything on this way since 2 days.Im not finding a guide how can i do a GET and get access token of paypal with objective-c?!

Comment: hmm are you trying to make these calls from your iOS app ? If so you shouldn't - that would be insecure since you would need to bundle your clientid/secret in your app on the client side. Please use a server side component to make these call to obtain the transacionId.