# Get PayPal Transaction Id-iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have used Paypal SDK in my app.
I can get app_id & pay_key as a proof of payment in my application.
But I am not able to get Transaction ID for the same.
I get to know that we can retrieve that id by GET method but I am not still able to get that ID.
Is there any example of request or any other method available for the same?
Please help me to solve this issue.
-Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using the new or the legacy SDK? For the new SDK, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435620/how-to-get-transactionid-on-paypal-ios-sdk-1-0-1

Answer (score 0):

The transaction id may be retrieved from your server using that authentication context.

- https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource (for credit cards)
- https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/ (for PayPal transactions)